# En angular 2, como obtener/regenerar una imagen almacenada en base de datos?

Tags: java, angularjs, base-de-datos, imagen

Tengo un backend realizado en java en donde persisto imágenes en una base de datos psql usando hibernate, las imágenes las estoy guardando en con el tipo de dato Byte[]. Por otro lado estoy desarrollando una aplicación cliente en angular 2, con esta aplicación cliente hice la conexión con el backend y consumí vía rest el objeto con su propiedad imagen. La pregunta es, como hago para regenerar la imagen del objeto consumido desde el servidor (propiedad en bytes) o alguna idea de como se trabaja con el  tratamiento de imágenes consumidas desde servidor y regeneradas en cliente ?. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

> Pide y almacena los bytes que representan tu imagen

```
const bytes = [];
```

> Convierte los bytes a un string en base64

```
const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(bytes)));
```

> Prepara la fuente de datos de la imagen

```
const source = `data:image/png;base64,${base64String}`;
```

> Dáselo a la imagen

```
<img [src]="source"/>
```